# Convert table into XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix

I have table as below

```
Project  Folder   Type     Type_Name    Name          Value
Project1  ABC    Workflow   wf_name   Batch_Table   Table_Name
Project1  ABC    Workflow   wf_name   Batch_Conn    JDBC
Project1  ABC    Mapping    mapp_name BALANCE_Table Bal_Table_Name
Project1  ABC    Mapping    mapp_name Schema        Schema_Name
```

And I need to convert that into the below XML. Is there any way we can achieve this in SQL Server?

I have attached the desired output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yydr4.png

Answer (score 2):

You can add `FOR XML PATH` to your query.